# Killing zombie processes in Linux

Tags: linux, process, zombie-process

I have a problem with zombie-processes. When I close the connection from the client side, zombie childs don't die. If I close the connection from the server side, everything is OK. There is no zombie child. I'm using the code below

Any Help ??

```
#define SERV_PORT   1051
#define LISTENQ     1024


void sig_chld(int signo)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int     stat;

    while ( (pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0)
        printf("child %d terminated\n", pid);
    return;
}


void *pThread_TCP(void *ptr)
{
    int                 listenfd, connfd;
    pid_t               childpid;
    socklen_t           clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in  cliaddr, servaddr;
    void                sig_chld(int);
    unsigned char       pData[255];
    unsigned short      n;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(SERV_PORT);

    struct ifreq ifr;
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "usb0");
    ioctl(listenfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);
    setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,  (void*)&ifr, sizeof(ifr));

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

    signal(SIGCHLD, sig_chld);  /* must call waitpid() */

    for ( ; ; ) {
        clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
        if ( (connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen)) < 0) 
        {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;       /* back to for() */
        }

        if ( (childpid = fork()) == 0)
        {   /* child process */
            while(1)
            {
                n = recvfrom(connfd,pData,100,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);
                if(n>0)
                {
                    if(pData[0] == '^') break;

                    sendto(connfd,"OK\r\n",4,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));

                }
            }
            close(listenfd);    /* close listening socket */
            exit(0);
        }
        close(connfd);          /* parent closes connected socket */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A zombie process consumes only the entry in the process table.  The kernel maintains it to allow for the parent process' `wait(2)` system call (and family) to be aware that there's actually a process to be waited for and don't fail about calling `wait()` without having subprocesses walking around.  Those walking dead processes are there to ensure kernel data consistency and, as such, you cannot kill them (even as root user)  The only way to ensure that a living parent doesn't have this bunch of zombies around is to do one `wait(2)` call for each `fork()` it has done before (which you don't do at all).  As in your code the thread is going to die just after closing the file descriptor, you have a chance to do a `waitpid(pid_of_child, ...);` there, so you'll wait for the proper child.  See `waitpid(2)` for more info about this system call.  This approach will have a non-visible drawback (your thread will last until the child dies).  The reason this works normally with processes (the non-need to do `wait()` in the parent process) is that you are not dying the parent (the parent lives after the thread dies) and so, the `fork()/wait()` relationship maintains.  When a parent dies, the kernel makes init (process with `id == 1`) the parent of your process, and `init(8)` is *always* making `wait(2)`s for the orphaned children in the system.

By just adding the following code after

```
    ...
    close(connfd);          /* parent closes connected socket */
    int retcode;  /* return code of child process */
    waitpid(childpid, &retcode, 0);
} /* for loop */
```

or, as you are not going to check how did the child terminate

```
    ...
    close(connfd);          /* parent closes connected socket */
    waitpid(childpid, 0, 0);
} /* for loop */
```

This has another drawback, is that you are going to wait for the child to terminate and will not get into the `accept(2)` system call before your child terminates, which can be not what you want.  If you want to avoid creating child zombie processes, there's another alternative (but it has some other drawbacks) is to ignore the `SIGCHLD` signal in the whole process, which makes the kernel not create those zombies (legacy way to do, there are other ways to avoid zombie children) or you can have a new thread just making the needed `wait()`s and dispatch the returned values from the children to the proper place, once they die.

Comment: @voyvoda, added!  is this a home assignment? if so, I think it's enough for now to include comment, you have to figure it, and read the man pages for info about the second and third parameters of `waitpid(2)` system call.

Comment: Why are you creating a whole process to deal with the connection, if you are using threads to manage the incoming connection socket? Why don't create a new thread to deal with the connection and share main data memory?  Have you thought in this way to solve the problem.  Threads and processes mean very different things, so mixing them in a project is almost always poor design.  Use threads or processes, but not both... more if you are not going to follow the `fork()` with an `exec()` to spawn a different program.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean "zombie process" (`Z` state in `ps`)? Those are already dead, but they haven't been reaped by their parent yet.

- The address arguments to `recvfrom`/`sendto` are useless on `SOCK_STREAM` sockets, and actually using values other than `NULL`/0 can fail on some implementations.
- TCP isn't message-based, so checking `pData[0]` is faulty. A client sending `"^A\r\n^B\r\n"` could legitimately be received as `"^"` followed by `"A\r\n^B\r\n"` or as `"^A\r\n^"` followed by `"B\r\n"` or any other split.
- It's possible that you get a short write while trying to send `"OK\r\n"`.
- If `recvfrom` returns `<0`, as it does in an error state like trying to read from a shutdown socket, you loop forever in `while(1)`. This is not a zombie - it's a running process, although one burning CPU for no use.
- In the parent process, you don't handle `SIGCHLD` nor call `wait`/`waitpid`/etc. This means that when children exit, they aren't reaped, and this will result in actual zombie processes.

Comment: Then What is your suggestion ?

Comment: Pass `send`/`recv` instead of `sendto`/`recvfrom` or pass `NULL` as the `sockaddr`/`addrlen` arguments. Buffer all data received from the client and process lines at a time. Buffer data to be sent to the client, and try to send again whatever hasn't been written yet when you can. If the return is negative, check `errno`; retry on `EINTR`, but you should terminate (probably `_exit`) on most other conditions. The easiest thing to do is set your `SIGCHLD` handler to `SIG_IGN`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining one by one. Could you please share an example related to my problem ?